# AWS S3 static website is not getting up from subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have created subdomain by following this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html) 'demo.mydomain.com' which is pointing s3 bucket static website (http://demo.mydomain.com.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com). Website is getting up from s3 link (http://demo.mydomain.com.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com). But When I am trying to access it from subdomain name its giving

```
This site can’t be reached
```

I have followed bellow step during creation of subdomain:

1. created subdomain(demo.mydomain.com) in hosted zone where my
   domain(mydomain.com) was already present.
2. created record with blank record name
3. Value/Route traffic to is 'Alias to s3 website end point'
4. select location where my s3 bucket available
5. select bucket and record type is IPv4

I couldn't figure it out what is I am missing. Any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> created record with blank record name

The record that you are creating in `mydomain.com` hosted zone **shouldn't be blank**. It should be called `demo` so that the full name, after the records creation, would be `demo.mydomain.com`. So it would look like something as below (depending on your region):

[image]